# Why {!$Label.c.myLabelName} is not working in lightning component added to VisualForce page?

Tags: aura, lightning

I'm trying to use custom labels in my lightning component project. The problem is {$Label.c.myLabelName} is not showing anything on one environment and is showing "[c.myLabelName]" string on the other. I also cannot retrieve labels with A$.get("$Label.c.myLabelName") in my init event handler, but it works when I call it later.
What is going on here? Is that a bug? Does anybody know a good workaround?

Comment: Does the org where the CL does not work have a namespace?

Comment: No, there are no namespaces on both orgs. $A.get("$Label.c.myLabelName") is working when called for example in a button click handler, but not when initializing the component and not as {!$Label...} expression.

Comment: can you post your component and controller code on how you are fetching custom label and setting the attribute on the component?

Answer (score 2):

This is my code works fine in developer org

component:

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="customlabl" type="String"/>
    hello : {!v.customlabl}
</aura:component>
```

controller:

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.customlabl",$A.get("$Label.c.Category"));
    }
})
```

> **Update: As mentioned in your comment, this could very well be a bug!!!**
>
> **1) The value of the label is not being set/ rendered on the VF
>   page for some reason.**
>
> **2) The aura app preview is breaking / not showing any output when I extend the app using `extends="ltng:outApp"`**

The only other workaround I can think of to handle label is to set the value of the label in the component controller through the VF page.

**Modified App:**

```
<aura:application access="GLOBAL" extends="ltng:outApp">
 <aura:dependency resource="prao6308:lcvfTestcomponent"/>
</aura:application>
```

**Modified component:**

```
<aura:component >
    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.doInit}"/>
    <aura:attribute name="customlabl" type="String"/>
    <aura:attribute name="customlablfromvf" type="String"/>
    <h1>Hello my value is set by  lightning controller: {!v.customlabl}</h1>
    <h1>Hello my value is set by  Visualforce page: {!v.customlablfromvf}</h1>    
</aura:component>
```

**Component controller ( same as above) :**

```
({
    doInit : function(component, event, helper) {
        component.set("v.customlabl",$A.get('$Label.c.Category'));
    }
})
```

**VF Page:**

I got an idea on setting attribute value based on blog by Peter Knolle and forcewizard's blog

http://forcewizard.com/blog/expose-your-lightning-components-visualforce-page

http://peterknolle.com/

( Look for Adding the Component to a Visualforce Page)

VF Page:

```
<apex:page standardStylesheets="false" showHeader="false" sidebar="false">
    <!-- Include a JavaScript file in your Visualforce page -->
    <apex:includeScript value="/lightning/lightning.out.js" />

    <div id="lightning" />
    <script>
    //Tell your Visualforce page to use ExposeVF Lightning app
        $Lightning.use("prao6308:lcvfTest", function() {
            // Write a function that creates the component on the page
          $Lightning.createComponent("prao6308:lcvfTestcomponent",
          {},
          "lightning",
          function(cmp) {
           cmp.set("v.customlablfromvf","{!$Label.Category}");
          });
        });
    </script>

</apex:page>
```

VF Page Output:
[image]

Comment: This works when I attach the component as lightning tab in SF1, but doesn't work when I use lightning component inside VisualForce page.

Comment: @maciek please look at my updated answer